# Movie with "Where do the tubes go?"

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to find a movie with an underground facility with people wearing white suits. The people have been affected such that they show no curiosity. There is one person that does and asks one of his co-workers where a tube leads to.

> At the end there is an uprising where everyone gets to see the surface and sunlight.

What is the name of this movie?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That sounds like it might be [The Island](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Island_(2005_film)), a 2005 film starring Ewan McGregor and Scarlett Johansson.

There is an uprising at the end with everyone seeing the surface, and here are some images of the people in the white suits.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The thing I remember most is the ridiculous Xbox product placement.

Comment: Ah yes, I remember that one, where Obi-Wan meets Black Widow.

Comment: @PointlessSpike not to mention the MSN phone boot.